# If URL's match in link and window, then add a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a match script to detect the page your on.. and to bold links that are also on the same page pointing to the page your currently on.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    var url = window.location.href;
    var match = $("a").attr("href");


    if(url == match) {
       $(match).parent().addClass("tomato");
    }


});
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
$('a[href~="'+url+'"]').addClass("tomato");
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('a').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.href) { 
        $(this).addClass('tomato');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var self = $(this);

    if (self.attr("href") == url) {
           // do something..
           self.css('font-weight', 'bold');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qbdTR/

Comment: It works, it didn't because your address was incorrect (jsfiddle works with iframe) http://jsfiddle.net/qbdTR/2/ (click 'Run').

Answer (score 0):

There was simple mistake in your code.

**var anchor = $("a"); 

var match = anchor.attr("href");

$(anchor).parent().....**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var anchor = $("a"); 
    var match = anchor.attr("href");

    if(url == match) {
       $(anchor).parent().addClass("tomato");
    }
});
```

It would be better if you can use;
1. parent with id or class - `$(anchor).parent('#anchorParent')` - Use the same id in HTML too.
2. Or use `$(anchor).parents('div:eq(0)')` for first div parent.

The same thing is applicable for anchor too HTML : `<a id="myAnchor">` , script : `$("#myAnchor");`